# How to increment value in Firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hopefully someone can help me with this. Lets say I have a post and I want to track down the number of clicks it gets. How do I go about incrementing the value in the database (Firebase). For example the post has one click that count as 1 then it has another click that counts as 2 then so on and so fourth. I tried doing something but I'm getting this error. I really need your help on this. Thanks in advance

Error message

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.myapp.poopy.Model_Information

My code

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://poopy-43981.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Post").child(getid);



  int count;

    count = count ++;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                    databaseReference.child("clicks").setValue(count+1);



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

  
        }
    });
```

Json

```
{
  "Post" : {
    "lG71ennq86UIZ5a5Oqh8oaYAXe03" : {
      "-MHNWmVK3rBnvnr0qcph" : {
        "clicks" : 0,
        "id" : "-MHNWmVK3rBnvnr0qcph",
  
        
      }
    }
  },
```

Model_class

```
 public Model_Information(String category, String headline, String  mImageUrl,String created,String time,String id,String status ) {

        this.mImageUrl =  mImageUrl;
        this.category = category;
        this.headline = headline;
        this.created=created;
        this.time=time;
        this.id=id;
        this.status=status;
    }

    public Model_Information() {

    }

    public String getstatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setstatus(String status) {
        status = status;
    }


    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }





    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }


    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    
    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

//Class using model class

 databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {



              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                  for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                      myUploads.clear();


                      Model_Information upload = postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);

                      myUploads.add(upload);
                      aAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity2.this, myUploads);
                      recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                      aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      recyclerView.invalidate();

                  }

              }

          }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON from your database at `/Post` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also: are you sure the error comes from the code you shared, as I don't see any use of `Model_Information` in there.

Comment: Btw: there is now an atomic `ServerValue.increment()` operation, which means you don't have to first read the value in your application code anymore. Once it's clear where the error comes from. I'll write an answer htat uses that operation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited my question and added Json

Comment: Thanks. Please check my edits, as it's best if you can already put the code/data into your question in the right format.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can use the ServerValue.increment()

Comment: There are two nested levels with dynamic keys under `Post`. The first level is the UID, which you handle in your code. The second level is a push ID, which your code is not handling from the looks up it. Given that there may be multiple child nodes under the UID: which one(s) do you want to increment the click count of?

Comment: That will be the push id

Comment: I understand that it's a push ID. But your code doesn't identify which child node/push Id under the UID needs to be incremented. Do you want to increment all of them? If not, do you have the push ID of the node whose `clicks` value you want to increment.

Comment: I also need to repeat that none of this code will throw the error you have in your question, as it doesn't use the `Model_Information` class that is mentioned in the error message  anywhere.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. But I thought I was using the push Id the whole time. I made sure I save a copy of the push id so It can access it that way

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm so sorry I left out the part where I saved a copy of the push id. I just edited my json code. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to update the `clicks` value you need to know the complete path to that value. In your use-case there seem to be two variables in that path:

- the UID
- a push ID

Once you know both values, increment the value can be done with the (relatively new) [`ServerValue.increment` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#increment(long)) like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://poopy-43981.firebaseio.com/");
DatabaseReference userReference = rootReference.child("Post").child(getid);
DatabaseReference countReference = userReference.child("-MHNWmVK3rBnvnr0qcph").child("clicks");

countReference.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

Comment: I got the complete path and I tried your answer but I get error saying No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue$NumericIncrementFieldValue

Comment: Oops, that's the operation for Firestore. For Realtime Database it's `ServerValue.increment`. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for that., but now I bump in to another problem. I get this error saying "Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.myapp.poopy.Model_Information" I edited my question and added the model class if that will help

Comment: None of the code in your question is using that class, to the error can't come from there. If the value is now incrementing, this question is addressed. I'd recommend searching for the error message of the new problem, as it's been covered quite a few times already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+Can%27t+convert+object+of+type and usually means you're reading from the wrong level in your JSON. If you can't figure it out, open a new question with the code that the stack trace points to and the JSON that is read there.

Comment: I see why its saying that. Because I have another class that opens first when I run the app and its using the Model class. I added the class that is using it Please take a look

Comment: Let me know if you post a new question, as I'm pretty sure I can help with that too. Then again: others might get to it before me, which is also fine of course. :)

Comment: I wont be needing to ask a question. I got it to work. I just had to change the path where I was saving the clicks because  I had the clicks and the post in the same database child and it was conflicting with the Model class.

Comment: Great to hear that you got it to work @Stephany.Star! 